# If-statment == never true?

Tags: python

I am writing a tic-tac-toe program to get more familiar with python and it seems to work accept for one if-statment when I make the computer make a move

Here is the function (within a class) with the if-statement that does not work as planed
I made a bunch of print statements just so I can see where the problem lies

```
   def bot_move(self):
      valid_move = 0
      
      while valid_move == 0:
         move = random.randint(1,9)
         
         print(f'bot move: {move}')
         
         for i in range(len(self.board)):
            
            print(f'self.board[i] = {self.board[i]}')
            
            for k in range(len(self.board[i])):
               
               print(f'self.board[{i}][{k}] = {self.board[i][k]}')
               print(f'self.board[{i}][{k}] == move: {self.board[i][k] == move}')
               
               if self.board[i][k] == move:
                  print('self.board[i][k] == move')
                  
                  self.board[i][k] = self.bot
                  valid_move = 1
```

The result that I get is:

```
bot move: 4
self.board[i] = ['X', '2', '3']
self.board[0][0] = X
self.board[0][0] == move: False
self.board[0][1] = 2
self.board[0][1] == move: False
self.board[0][2] = 3
self.board[0][2] == move: False
self.board[i] = ['4', '5', '6']
self.board[1][0] = 4
self.board[1][0] == move: False
self.board[1][1] = 5
self.board[1][1] == move: False
self.board[1][2] = 6
self.board[1][2] == move: False
self.board[i] = ['7', '8', '9']
self.board[2][0] = 7
self.board[2][0] == move: False
self.board[2][1] = 8
self.board[2][1] == move: False
self.board[2][2] = 9
self.board[2][2] == move: False
```

What I see is: move = 4, self.board[1][0] = 4, move == self.board[1][0] is false
But why does `self.board[1][0] == move` return false?

[Link to view the full program](https://pastebin.com/Fk6brC4w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason **self.board[1][0] == move** returns **false** is because the elements in your **self.board** list are strings, while **move** is an integer.

In Python, the equality operator (==) compares the values of the operands.

In your code, **self.board[1][0]** is the string '**4**', while **move** is the integer **4**. Since a string and an integer are different types, the equality comparison will return False. To fix this, you can convert **move** to a string before comparing it with **self.board[1][0]**.

```
def bot_move(self):
valid_move = 0

while valid_move == 0:
    move = random.randint(1, 9)

    print(f'bot move: {move}')

    for i in range(len(self.board)):
        print(f'self.board[i] = {self.board[i]}')

        for k in range(len(self.board[i])):
            print(f'self.board[{i}][{k}] = {self.board[i][k]}')
            print(f'self.board[{i}][{k}] == move: {self.board[i][k] == str(move)}')

            if self.board[i][k] == str(move):
                print('self.board[i][k] == move')

                self.board[i][k] = self.bot
                valid_move = 1
```

By converting **move** to a string using **str(move)**, you can compare it with the string value in **self.board[1][0]** and the comparison will yield the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `string` to an `int`. Simply:

```
if self.board[i][k] == str(move):
```

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the `play()` function you run `self.reset()`, which resets you board to be list of lists of strings

`self.board = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]`

However, `move` is int, so the comparison between board and move always fails.
`move = random.randint(1,9)`

Interestingly, in `__init__` you set the board as list of lists of ints

`self.board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

So maybe stick with this initiation when reseting.

Answer (score 1):

Python's equal comparator is strict except for when comparing 1 to True, and 0 to False.

In Python:

```
4 == '4'  # False
4 == ''  # False
```

It must be:-

```
 4 == 4
```

Either you change initial types or just do it while testing like this:--

```
self.board[i][k] == str(move)
```